# convert store currency to another currency at the checkout end without using multi store

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

What options do we have in current web site to show NZD amounts and then convert it to AUD at the checkout end... is it possible to do this?.. so we can handle the payments from  Australia using another payment service with AUD.Here is only one store for New Zealand

Answer (score 0):

1. System > Configuration > Currency Setup

   Select  Base Currency and Default Display Currency as follows

[image]

2. System > Manage Currency > Rates

add details

[image]

3. Then you will get like this in checkout page

[image]